# Creating Route Event layer with Right Angle?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, linear-referencing

I have collected GPS points along the road. and got Right angle Tape measurements of Boundary walls and other objects from that respective points. I have those records in Excel Sheet and GPS observation is in Shp file. Now I want to plot those points. I Have Tried with Linear referencing Tool in Arcmap. The events were created as point layer but that is not in Right Angle... How to Solve this?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you have and want to achieve. Do you have a line calibrated with measure for linear referencing, and then a set of measurements given as <measure>, <distance to the side> ?

Comment: Agree with the above comment. Sounds like you have offset measurements at station points, to add a couple more terms to your potential search. Linear referencing isn't really relevant to what you want to do - that's more for establishing points *along* a line. You already have the points (GPS points) and want to create more points a given distance *away* from a reference line (the road). It would be easy, if time consuming, to do manually, but off-hand I don't know of an automatic solution.

Comment: So are you saying you want to follow the road or be at a Normal angle to the road?  The Normal angle to the road is handled by the side offset field and the distance along the road is handled by the measure field of a point or line event.  From a point event measure I can add or subtract any distance in the measure field and set another point along the road relative to that point (as long as the measure is on the road), or with two measures I can set a line segment along the road.  With a side offset field those points or lines can be offset to the left or right.  So clarify what you want.

Comment: Yep.. I Want to draw 2 lines. First The Road Edge. Its can be obtain from Line to Polyline tool because I Have Collected All the Key points (Nodes and Turnings). My Problem is Drawing The Building Line. Its only have Offset values from Road Edge. I Thought it can be obtain from Linear Reference tool... But I Observed the offset is not in Right Angle.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the normal angle or tangent angle or the compliment to either of those angles for any point event along a Route.  You can then use the Bearing and Distance to Line tool to set lines extending from your event on that angle bearing and extract the To End Point of the line with the Feature Vertices to Point tool to get a new point.  If you just want to follow the road a certain distance from your original point event, you just add or subtract the distance you want to offset from the original point measure to move that distance up or down the road (as long as the measure stays within the measure range of the route).  The optional Side Offset field value can also offset a point event left or right of a line as a starting point using a positive or negative side distance number.  So all forms of Right angles and Normal angles and road following and road offsets are possible with LR and possibly a couple tools from the Feature toolset.  So please clarify your goal better.